# Kial ne ekzistas "post ol <verbo>"?

Tags: prepositions

Jen estas [paĝo](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/i-verboj/kun_rolvortetoj.html) de PMEG. Ĉe la parto pri "aliaj rolvortetoj", estas dirite, ke oni povas diri "antaŭ ol <i-verbo>", sed ial ne "**post** ol <i-verbo>". Speciale konsiderante tion, ke "post" teĥnike estas la malo de "antaŭ", kial ekzistas tia neperpendikularaĵo?

Comment: Mi ne scias ĉu perpendikularaĵo aplikeblas al lingva afero ... ĉiuokaze `ort-` estus kaj bonlingva kaj multe pli mallonga.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mallonge, rekte el [vortara difino de post](https://vortaro.net/#post_kd):

> post ol, kvankam preskaŭ ne uzata, estas uzebla analoge al antaŭ ol.

Do, responde al via demando: la eblo ja ekzistas.

Sed vi povas uzi pli simplan kaj oftan (kaj *simetrian*) formon:

```
antaŭ trinki/komenci/plori

post serĉi/pagi/manĝi
```

Ekzemplo el Tekstaro:

```
Tamen antaŭ eldoni libron, oni devas ĝin verki.
```

Fine de la paĝo, [kiun vi menciis](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/i-verboj/kun_rolvortetoj.html), oni klarigas kiel la lingva evoluo ŝanĝas la regulon, kiujn oni difinas tie kiel *arbitran tabuon*.

> La Esperanta tradicio estas malfacile klarigebla per logikaj argumentoj. Esence ĝi estas arbitra tabuo.
> [...]
>
> Pli kaj pli ofte oni aŭdas frazojn kun rolvortetoj kiel pri, pro, dum, post k.a. antaŭ I-verbo

Poste venas ekzemploj. Tiu ĉi spegulas mian lingvouzon, kaj do mi ĝin citas:

```
Tradicie: Tuj post kiam li enlitiĝis...
Nuntempe: Tuj post enlitiĝi li ekdormis.
          Tuj enlitiĝinte...
```

Mi nur uzas la duan aŭ trian formon. La tradician mi opinias nebezonate peza. Fakte ĉiuj `post kiam ..is` iĝas por mi `...inte`. La tri ebloj bonas, kaj nia lingvo vivas kaj evoluas, tio estas bona novaĵo.

Comment: Parentezo: La tria formo ŝajnas al mi kiel frazekvivalento . Sed mia denaska lingvo permesas, ke tiaj ekvivalentoj havas aliajn subjekton ol tiu, kiu estas la fraza subjekto. Mi scias, ke la espa tio ne eblas. Ĉiuokaze vi pravas, ke estas bone havi alternativon al la unua. Mi ne povas akcepti la duan esprimon, ĉar la infinitivo ne montras tempon, do ne povas esti poste iu okaĵo, kiu estas sentempa)..

Comment: Laŭ mia lingvosento (kaj deziro al reguleco kaj logikeco), la plej grava regulo estas ke “ol” taŭgas antaŭ i-verbo kaj “kiam” taŭgas antaŭ subjekto+{-is/-as/-os}. Krom tio, ne gravas ĉu vi uzas ilin kun “antaŭ” aŭ “post”, ambaŭ eblas. Ĉi tiu respondo diras ke oni povas forlasi “ol”, sed kelkfoje mi opinias ĝin utila por distingi lokon kaj tempon: antaŭ la revolucio (fronte al ĝi); antaŭ ol la revolucio (pli frue ol ĝi) [jes, mi rimarkis ke ĉi tie mi ne uzis i-verbon, sed o-vorton]. Ĉu mi pravas?

Comment: Ho ve, mi ĵus trovis multajn ekzemplojn de “antaŭ ol subjekto -is/-as/-os” do mia instinkta regulo pri “ol” kaj “kiam” fakte ne estas tiel valida kiel mi pensis.

Comment: @JuhaMetsäkallas en la esperanta mi sentas la infinitivon kiel preskaŭ substantivon, kvazaŭ ĝi estus la nomo de la ago. Do, la dua frazo povus esti `tuj post enlitiĝo...`, ĉu tio pli akcepteblus? La tempon, modon, ktpn. fiksas la dua parto de la frazo.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani, jes, PMEG havas ĉapitron pri [_tempa post_](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/rolvortetoj/lokaj_rolvortetoj/post.html#i-ja9). En ĉiuj ekzemploj oni havas  substantivon post "post", kaj tiuj substantivoj povas montri okazaĵon, ekz. "enlitiĝo".

Answer (score 2):

Mi suspektas (kaj bedaŭras) ke la respondo estas verŝajne pro influoj de naciaj lingvoj.

Multaj naciaj lingvoj havas formon kiel X-inte kaj pro tio ĝi ŝajnas natura al multaj esperantistoj:

- Having got up late, I missed my bus
- M’étant levé tard, j’ai raté le bus
- Leviĝinte malfrue, mi maltrafis la buson

Tamen en la angla kaj latinidaj lingvoj, ne estas facila maniero diri X-onte kaj do oni uzas prepozicion anstataŭe:

- I took a shower before going to work
- Je me suis douché avant d’aller au travail
- Mi duŝiĝis antaŭ ol iri al la laboro [aŭ teorie: mi duŝiĝis ironte al la laboro]

Do verŝajne pro tio oni kutimas uzi prepozicion por “antaŭ”, kaj adverban formon por “post”.

Comment: Sed ĉu estas nepre malĝuste uzi "post ol", aŭ ĉu estas nur nekutime pro tia influo?

Comment: La malo de "antaŭ ol" estas "post kiam", sed oni havas plenan subfrazon poste tiu esprimo. Ekz. "Post kiam mi duŝiĝis, mi iris al la laboro." aŭ "Post kiam mi duŝiĝos, mi iros al la laboro."